# Add "Branch Control" on {{Azure DevOps : Variable Group}} using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement to add or enable "Branch Control" on Azure DevOps{{Approvals and checks for Library}}. Is there a Rest API for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSqox.png)